# How to select first value from array in a foreach loop when passing variable on same page?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

code:

```
$persons = array();
$tags = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
  if(!isset($persons[$row["id"]])) { 
    $persons[$row["id"]]= $row; 
    $tags[ $row['id'] ] = array();
  }
  $tags[ $row['id'] ][] = $row['tag'];
}     

foreach($persons as $pid=>$p){ 
  $tag1 = $p["tag"];
  $tag1ish = $tags[$p['id']];
}
```

Comment: You mean how to get the first element of the array?

Comment: @mosty mostacho yes. Get the first element of the tags array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($persons as $pid=>$p){ 
  $tag1 = $p["tag"];
  $tag1ish = $tags[$p['id']];

  /* to get the first tag, there are many options e.g.: */

  $first_tag = $tag1ish[0]; // given u use [] syntax as above.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid calling a foreach and just use the first element

```
$tag1 = $persons[0]["tag"];
```

or use [current](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php):

```
$tag1 = current($persons);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the clarification didn't help much :P Anyway, I'd reccomend to order the tags by ID then (or at least alphabetically). So the order of the tags will be the same and accessing the first element of the array would return always the same tag.

Comment: hmmm this is what I want but I can't think of it right now. Thanks for clearing it up a bit. I do have my ranks that numbers my tags from 1 to 4.

Comment: I'm not sure about ranks, but IDs are unique, that is your best option. Probably adding it in the SQL code or even sorting the array in PHP might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand well, you can use the reset() function. It received an array as argument and returns the first element.

Comment: no, reset — `Set the internal pointer of an array to its first element`

Comment: and returns the value of the first array element.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($persons as $pid=>$p){
  // is this what you mean..?
  $theTagYouWant = $tags[0];
  $tag1 = $p["tag"];
  $tag1ish = $tags[$p['id']];
}
```